# Repeat function after slowest of: previous function completes, or x seconds have passed

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

Say I have an asynchronous function `inconsistentDurationAsync` which can take any amount of time to complete, probably less than a minute but commonly between 0 seconds and 30 seconds. I can't predict how long the function will take to complete.

I want to run this function every `timeout` milliseconds, but only if it has already completed.

If it hasn't completed yet, I'd like to wait for it to complete before calling it again.

My code at the moment, boiled down as simply as possible, is simply a

```
setInterval(inconsistentDurationAsync, timeout);
```

But clearly it doesn't check if the function has completed before calling it again.

Comment: Use a promise to keep track of completion, just remember to set it back to nothing after starting a new interval.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `active` flag, and whenever the method is invoked set it to `true`, and when it's done set it to `false`. If it's already `true` when `inconsistentDurationAsync` is invoke, use `return` to break out of the function.

```
var active = false;

function inconsistentDurationAsync() {
  if(active) {
    return;
  }
  active = true;

  console.log('Do something');

  active = false; // in async code, place this in the callback that gets invoked when everything is done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I'll just describe the common paradigm for this issue, this applies to any language:

- Set `minInterval` to the minimum task execution interval
- Remember current time as `startTime`
- start your long task
- Once the task has completed calculate `remainingTime = minInterval - (currentTime - startTime)`
- IFF `remainingTime > 0`  wait `remainingTime` in time units
- go back to step 1.

Node.js example (assuming you're using some `Promise` implementation, such as bluebird:

```js
// In node you might need: const Promise = require("bluebird")
    const MIN_INTERVAL = 4*1000;

    if(!Promise.delay) {
        Promise.delay = function(duration) {
            return new Promise((res,rej)=>setTimeout(res, duration));
        };
    }
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    async function inconsistentDurationAsync() {
        await Promise.delay(getRandomInt(100, 10*1000));
    }
    var shouldDoStuff = true;
    async function doStuff() {
        while(shouldDoStuff) {
            const startTime = new Date().getTime();
            await inconsistentDurationAsync();
            const duration = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
            const remainingTime = MIN_INTERVAL - duration;
            if(remainingTime>0)
                await Promise.delay(remainingTime);
            console.log("Done. Duration: ", duration,"ms; Sleep: ", Math.max(0, remainingTime), "ms");
            if(document && document.body) {
                var div = document.createElement("div")
                div.appendChild(new Text("Done. Duration: "+ duration+"ms; Sleep: "+ Math.max(0, remainingTime)+ "ms"));
                document.body.appendChild(div);
            
            }
        }
    }
    doStuff();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using two promises:

- One has the minimum interval duration. This promise will fulfill after a set amount of time has lapsed. It replaces the `setTimeout`.
- The other promise will be fulfilled whenever the task with an unknown duration is finished.

Only once both promises have been fulfilled will it start again.

```js
function asyncTask(duration) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, duration);
  });
}

function minDurationPromise() {
  console.log('Starting min duration promise of 3000ms');
  // Return the async task with a 3000ms duration, log a message once it is done.
  return asyncTask(3000).then(() => console.log('min duration lapsed'));
}

function randomDurationPromise() {
  const
    // Create a random duration for the async task.
    randomDuration = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4000) + 1000;
  
  console.log(`Starting random duration promise of ${randomDuration}ms`);
  // Return the async task with a random duration, log a message once it is done.
  return asyncTask(randomDuration).then(() => console.log('random duration lapsed'));
}

function doSomething() {
  console.log('Starting both promises');
  // Wait for both async tasks to be completed...
  Promise.all([minDurationPromise(), randomDurationPromise()])
    .then(() => {
      // ... when both are done log a message...
      console.log('both promise fullfilled');
      // ...and start again.
      doSomething();
    });
}

doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

Every end point of your function need to have the setTimeout.
Promises are not fitting that goal.

```
function inconsistentDurationAsync()
{
    function doneCallback()
    {
        // complete your last callback in the chain
        setTimeout(inconsistentDurationAsync, timeout);
    }
}
```